# String substution in BASH

Tags: bash

```
$ echo $billreminder
D:\juno_workspace_x64\9.0.4_app\moneycenter\src\webapp\jsp\billreminder

billreminder="${$billreminder/'D:'/ '\\cygdrive\\d' }"
```

(this returns BAD SUBSTUTION on cyg-win console windows)

i want to replace 'D:\' with '/cygdrive/d' in above string billreminder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can you string substitution if you prefer, but using cygwin you can also use the command [cygpath](http://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using-utils.html#cygpath).

This command convert the parameter supplied as path in Windows-style to path in cygwin-style, you can use it as follow:

```
b=$(cygpath $b)
```

Comment: +1 this is the right way to work in CYGWIN environment, the other answers are playing around only (include the accepted one), which can't identify the difference of windows path `(\)` and Unix path `(/)`.

Answer (score 2):

Say:

```
billreminder="${billreminder/D:/\\cygdrive\\d}"
```

Comment: this works , was giving bad substution error when a space was left between billreminder and /D:/ , and i didnt knew before it could work without quotes on strings , also the replacement string (in question) should have been in double quotes to escape /

Answer (score 1):

You can use this substitution:

```
s='D:\juno_workspace_x64\9.0.4_app\moneycenter\src\webapp\jsp\billreminder'
echo "${s/D:\\//cygdrive/d\\}"
/cygdrive/d\juno_workspace_x64\9.0.4_app\moneycenter\src\webapp\jsp\billreminder
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply remove the second `$` sign:

```
~/> echo ${billreminder/'D:'/ '\\cygdrive\\d'}
\\cygdrive\\d\juno_workspace_x64\9.0.4_app\moneycenter\src\webapp\jsp\billreminder
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it this way:

```
b='D:\juno_workspace_x64\9.0.4_app\moneycenter\src\webapp\jsp\billreminder' 
b=\\cygdrive\\d\\${b#D:\\}
echo $b
```

Comment: i want to assign the result to a variable , `echo /cygdrive/d/${b#D:\\}` does not work here

Comment: it does: b=\\cygdrive\\d\\${b#D:\\} I'll do the edit